# Solving this Recurrence Relation in terms of previous values.

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

What will be the value of $X(n)$ and $Y(n)$ in terms of given $n,X(0),Y(0)$.

$$
X(n) = X(n-1) + Y(n-1) \\
Y(n) = 2X(n-1) + Y(n-1)
$$

Comment: You can use matrices for this.

Comment: can you elaborate it,sir?

Comment: Since $\begin{bmatrix}X(n)\\Y(n)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}^n
\begin{bmatrix}X(0)\\Y(0)\end{bmatrix}
$, what you need to do is find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$ and then express $\begin{bmatrix}X(0)\\Y(0)\end{bmatrix}$ in terms of the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that:
$$
\begin{matrix}
x_n - x_{n-1} = y_{n-1} \\
y_n - y_{n-1} = 2x_{n-1}
\end{matrix}
$$
by subtracting the first relation for $y_n$ and $y_{n-1}$:
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n - x_n + x_{n-1} = y_n - y_{n-1} = 2x_{n-1}
$$
Thus:
$$
x_{n+1} - 2x_n - x_{n-1} = 0
$$
which is a linear one variable recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

This relation can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}X(n) \\ Y(n)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X(n - 1) \\ Y(n - 1)\end{pmatrix}. $$

If you define $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, this yields 
$$\begin{pmatrix}X(n) \\ Y(n)\end{pmatrix} = A^n \begin{pmatrix}X(0) \\ Y(0)\end{pmatrix}. $$

Now you only need to calculate the powers of $A$, this works straightforward via diagonalzation.

Comment: I've shown you the right idea to solve this problem, now it's your turn to calculate the powers of $A$. Please note that this site is meant to help you with mathematical problems, not solve your exercises. It's expected of members to show some initiative of their own.

Answer (score 0):

This linear recurrence may be represented matricially:
$$\begin{bmatrix}X_n\\Y_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}X_{n-1}\\Y_{n-1}\end{bmatrix},$$
hence
$$\begin{bmatrix}X_n\\Y_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}X_0\\Y_0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Set $\;A= \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$. To compute $A^n$, you have to find the Jordan normal form of $A$: $J=D+N$, where $D$  is a diagonal matrix, with the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal, and $N$ is a nilpotent matrix which commutes with $D$. It is then easy to ompute powers of $J$, as we can use the binomial formula, and $N$ has a finite number of non-zero powers. The last step consists in going back from $J^n$ to $A^n$ by the change of basis formula: if $J=P^{-1}AP$,we also have $J^n=P^{-1}A^nP$, whence $\;A^n=PJ^nP^{-1}$.

In the present case it is simple: $A$ is diagonalisable:  its eigenvalues are $1\pm\sqrt2$, the corresponding eigenvectors are $\;\begin{bmatrix}1\\\mp\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$, so that the change of basis matrix is
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-\sqrt2&\sqrt2\end{bmatrix},\quad D=\begin{bmatrix}1+\sqrt2 & 0\\-0&1-\sqrt2\end{bmatrix},\quad P^{-1}=\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2&-\sqrt2\\2&\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}, $$

whence, if I'm not mistaken:
$$A^n=\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2\bigl((1+\sqrt2)^n+((1-\sqrt2)^n\bigr) &\sqrt2\bigl((1-\sqrt2)^n-((1+\sqrt2)^n\bigr)\\2\sqrt2\bigl((1-\sqrt2)^n-((1+\sqrt2)^n\bigr)&2\bigl((1+\sqrt2)^n+((1-\sqrt2)^n\bigr)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

One instructive solution is to use generating functions. Define:

$\begin{align}
f(z)
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} X(n) z^n  \\
g(z)
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} Y(n) z^n
\end{align}$

Shift indices to get:

$\begin{align}
X(n + 1)
  &= X(n) + Y(n) \\
Y(n + 1)
  &= 2 X(n) + Y(n)
\end{align}$

Multiply the recurrences by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize the resulting sums:

$\begin{align}
\frac{f(z) - X(0)}{z}
  &= f(z) + g(z) \\
\frac{g(z) - Y(0)}{z}
  &= 2 f(z) + g(z)
\end{align}$

This gives:

$\begin{align}
f(z)
  &= \frac{X(0) + (Y(0) - X(0)) z}{1 - 2 z - z^2} \\
g(z)
  &= \frac{Y(0) - 2 (Y(0) - 2 X(0)) z}{1 - 2 z - z^2}
\end{align}$

This can be written as partial fractions, the denominator factors as $(1 - (1 - \sqrt{2}) z) (1 - (1 + \sqrt{2}) z)$. The result is quite ugly, but you'll get terms of the form:

$$
\frac{1}{1 - \alpha z}
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} \alpha^n z^n
$$

so that the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ are immediate.